# ASP.NET forum with MongoDB

Tags: forum, mongodb, asp.net

I am trying to find an a forum engine that is built with ASP.NET and MongoDB.

I have found a lot of forum engines that are open source with ASP.NET and MSSQL and MySQL but none with MongoDB.

Examples

- http://www.yetanotherforum.net/
- http://www.mvcforum.org/

Has anyone found implementation of these that works with MongoDB?